# Client/Server, Asynchronous ping-pong exchange

Tags: c#, networking, async-await

I'm mainly wondering about whether or not I have used the (TAP) async/await pattern correctly. I get a bunch of these warnings, "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed.", however that sounds like exactly what I want. Which is for the server to be able to handle clients independently and asynchronously.

As a side note, I know it's bad for performance to re-initialize the streams in for example HandleConnection, I just kept it that way for brevity's sake.

Client.cs:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Client {
    TcpClient tcpClient;
    public void Connect() {
        ConnectAsync();
    }

    public async void Ping() {
        await SendMessage("Ping!");
    }

    private async Task ConnectAsync() {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3344);
        MainWindow.ClientLog("Connected to server!");

        HandleConnection(tcpClient);
    }

    private async Task HandleConnection(TcpClient tcpClient) {
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        string message = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
        MainWindow.ClientLog("Received message from server: " + message);

        HandleConnection(tcpClient);
    }

    private async Task SendMessage(string message) {
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        MainWindow.ClientLog("Sent Ping! to server.");
    }
}
```

Server.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Server {
    List<TcpClient> connectedClients;
    public void Host() {
        connectedClients = new List<TcpClient>();
        HostAsync();
    }

    private async Task HostAsync() {
        IPEndPoint local = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3344);
        TcpListener mainListener = new TcpListener(local);

        mainListener.Start();
        MainWindow.ServerLog("Server started.");
        while(true) {
            TcpClient client = await mainListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            MainWindow.ServerLog("Client connected!");

            connectedClients.Add(client);
            HandleClient(client);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client) {
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        string message = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
        MainWindow.ServerLog("Message from client nr. " + connectedClients.IndexOf(client) + ": " + message);

        if (message == "Ping!") {
            await SendMessage(client, "Pong!");
        }

        HandleClient(client);
    }

    private async Task SendMessage(TcpClient client, string message) {
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        MainWindow.ServerLog("Sent message to client: " + message);
    }

    private async Task SendMessages(IEnumerable<TcpClient> clients, string message) {
        foreach (TcpClient client in clients) {
            SendMessage(client, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work as intended or not? Your question seems ambiguous about this.

Comment: As far as I'm able to tell/test, it works as intended. However I suspect this isn't the right way of going about things, and that there are gotchas I have missed. From other posts I've looked at there seems to at least be issues regarding unhandled exceptions with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it seems to be only a "warning". Async/Await are supposed to be used as a pair in most cases. Let's have a simple example based on your code :

```
 HostAsync();
```

Here you have written a basic method call, and the method is :

```
private async Task HostAsync()
```

So the warning appears because compiler is expecting something like :

```
await ...
```

inside the HostAsync method.

By not putting the await keyword inside this async method, we get basically a synchronous call, a standard method. Not a big issue in most cases but have a look at :

```
private async Task SendMessages(IEnumerable<TcpClient> clients, string message)
```

This one has no await too.

Hope this helps !

Comment: It doesn't seem to turn into a synchronous call at all. For example, if I convert HostAsync to a regular non-async method, the UI thread would freeze while it waits for connections.

Comment: The intention is to run HostAsync in a different "thread" (task), so that the rest of my program can keep running separately from it. Similarly I want each client to be handled by separate tasks (HandleClient-s).

SendMessages doesn't have an await, because I want it to just fire off messages and forget about them, I can't "await" any meaningful result because it could send a message that the client doesn't have to respond to.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed something  : I think  a better explanation was a call Inside a new task. Now the real difference is linked to how exception are handled with or without the await keyword.